# C# Google.ProtocolBuffers Deserialization Method (proto3)

Tags: c#, deserialization, protocol-buffers, proto3

I have recently upgraded my code base (Java, C++ and C#) to use proto3. In the case of C# this has involved over 2000 changes to the code. This is mostly semantic and all good, but there is one issue I can't seem to fathom; serialization/deserialization. I have the following amended method to desearialize my `IMessage` types (the code to do this in proto2 is commented), this is the code that is show in the examples within the GitHub repository...

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this byte[] buf) where T : IMessage 
{
    if (buf == null)
        return default(T);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MessageParser parser = new MessageParser();
        return (T)parser.ParseFrom(ms);
            //ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
    }
}
```

but the line `MessageParser parser = new MessageParser();` is giving me a design/compile-time error

> MessageParser does not contain a constructor that contains 0 aguments

Well that is curious as I know about [proto3 documents](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser_1a0d6dd59d95463e0884cc7e168e12246f) that tell me the contrary.

All I want to know is, using proto3, how I can perform my deserialization?

Thanks for your time.

---

Note, my serialization code is

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T o) where T : IMessage 
{
    if (o == null)
        return null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        o.WriteTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This compiles, but is it right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your deserialization compile time error, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser_1a0d6dd59d95463e0884cc7e168e12246f) told that **you should pass a `Func<T>` as a function factory to create instances of `T` to the constructor of `MessageParser<T>`**.

It could be `() => new T()` or a more complicated function depending on what it needs to create your messages.

**Full code:**

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this byte[] buf) where T : IMessage<T>, new()
{
    if (buf == null)
        return default(T);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MessageParser<T> parser = new MessageParser<T>(() => new T());
        return parser.ParseFrom(ms);
    }
}
```

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-message) says the serialization should be ok.

Comment: Hi, I totally missed that part of the documentation. I must have went temporally blind! I have tweaked your code so that it compiles. Two things were wrong. 1. `IMessage` could not be boxed/un-boxed without specifying the type `T`. 2. Neded the `new()` constraint in order to be able to "new-up" a `T`. Thanks for your time...